# Filtering Recycler View with Clickable Object

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecycleView with CardView in it settled in rows. On click of any row opens a new Activity associated to that row. Everything was working great until I added the filter functionality to this list. When I search the list and then click on one Item, it doesn't do function associated with the filtered results.

Example : Original List : A,B,C,D,E

Search : 'B' Filtered results: B

But when I click on item B it do function in item A
Since i have two lists, which the original and the one to store the filtered list, how to make filtered list object, able to do function to update the original list/ take position of original list object.

```
searchdev.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            filter(editable.toString());
}});

public void filter (String search){
    ArrayList<Devices> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Devices item : devicelist){
        if (item.getDevicename().toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase()))
        {
            filteredList.add(item);
        }
    }
    DevAdapter.filterList(filteredList);
    devicelist = filteredList;

}
```

Click function:

```
DevAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ListAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReturnClick(int position) {
            String renter = devicelist.get(position).getRenter();
            final String childpos = String.valueOf(position);

            if( name.equals(renter)) // sesuai renter
            {
                Toast.makeText(RentActivity.this,"Device RETURNED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                devicedb.child(childpos).child("codereturn").setValue("-");
                devicedb.child(childpos).child("statusdb").setValue("0");
                devicedb.child(childpos).child("statuscard").setValue("Available");
                devicedb.child(childpos).child("renter").setValue("-");

                devicelist.get(position).changeOnReturn("-","Available");
                DevAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
               else
            {
                Toast.makeText(RentActivity.this,"Not Eligible for Returning",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onRentClick(int position) {
            String checkstats=devicelist.get(position).getStatuscard();
            final String childpos = String.valueOf(position);
            if(checkconnection(RentActivity.this)) {
                if (checkstats.equals("Available")) {
                    devicedb.child(childpos).child("codereturn").setValue("-");
                    devicedb.child(childpos).child("statusdb").setValue("1");
                    devicedb.child(childpos).child("statuscard").setValue("Rented");
                    devicedb.child(childpos).child("renter").setValue(name);
                    Toast.makeText(RentActivity.this,"Device Rent Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    devicelist.get(position).changeOnRent(name,"Rented");
                    DevAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(RentActivity.this, "Device not Available to Rent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(RentActivity.this, "NO INTERNET ACCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    });
```

and the adapter :

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return devlist.size();
}

public void filterList(ArrayList<Devices> filteredlist){
        devlist = filteredlist;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: To get item position on recyclerview adapter use getAdapterPosition()
 int pos = getAdapterPosition();

Comment: Your position value will be different.  Ensure that you parse the correct adapter position to the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Because i have 2 array lists, which are the ORIGINAL and the FILTERED, so i have to bring the ORIGINAL position to the FILTERED one, in order the filtered list point the correct position of the Original one.

So i manually add the original position of the data in orpos variable :

```
public Devices(String orpos,String devname, String codedev, String renter, String statusdb, String statuscard, String img) {
    this.oriposition = orpos;
    this.devicename = devname;
    this.codereturn = codedev;
    this.renter = renter;
    this.statusdb = statusdb;
    this.statuscard = statuscard;
    this.img = img;

}
```

And in Filter function i make new adapter which contain the filtered list  :

```
public void filter (final String search){
    final ArrayList<Devices> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Devices item : devicelist){
        if (item.getDevicename().toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase()))
        {
            filteredList.add(item);
        }


    }

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.devlist);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    DevAdapter = new ListAdapter(filteredList);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(DevAdapter);


    DevAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ListAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReturnClick(int position) {
            int positionnew = Integer.parseInt(filteredList.get(position).getOriposition());
            String renter = devicelist.get(positionnew).getRenter();
            final String childpos = String.valueOf(positionnew);
            ...
```

I make new variable called positionnew to overwrite the filtered list array number with the original list array number :

```
int positionnew = Integer.parseInt(filteredList.get(position).getOriposition());
```